# Boostrap progress bar loading but then disappearing

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I'm [building a site](http://myadt.us/homesecurity.php) with Twitter Bootstrap, and on a couple of pages I have a progress bar that loads in but then it disappears. I'd like it to load and stay.

[Here's the website](http://myadt.us/homesecurity.php) and the page as to which I'm referring. The progress bar is on the right hand side.

The JavaScript code in `custom.js` is the following:

```
/* ------------------ Progress Bar ------------------- */   
$(function() {
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 1200);
    });
});
```

Comment: setting is wrong, double check

Comment: Please include the relevant code (Javascript, HTML snippet) in the question or link to a small JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after the animation plays, you didn't set the original width back, so it just displays the bar with the modified 0 width.

Change the Progress Bar part in your `custom.js` file to this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        var width = $(this).width();
        $(this)
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: width
            }, 1200)
            .width(width);
    });
});
```